Redis as cache for postgreSql nested data
I'm working on web app using nestJs/postgres/redis.
What is the best way (best data structure) to cache following postgres table (hierarchy) to Redis ?
space:

name
another attribute
users (one2many)

folders:

spaceId
name
users (one2many)

files:

folderId
spaceId
name
users (one2many).

I already tried to cache this using key-value where the key is hashed from request and value is response of say getAllMyFiles but there will be some problem
Say i want to cache The route:
/my-files

key: users:[USER_ID]:documents:[QUERY-HASH]
the problem is that:

i have to cache this for every user and thus the cache will get bigger
when updating one file i have to invalidate the entire files-cache for all the users


You can't really talk about "best" for a cache without being very precise about your usage patterns.

I think that the best solution is to use Redis graph

Could this be a good candidate for RedisJSON? You could store the entire space and all its hierarchy in a single key as JSON using JSON.SET and then query portions of it using JSON.GET.
JSON.SET space:1234 $ '{
  "name": "foo",
  "users": [ "alice", "bob" ],
  "folders": [
    {
      "id": "5678",
      "files": [ 
        {
          "name": "bar"
        },
        ...other files...
      ]
    },
    ...other folders...
  }'

JSON.GET space:1234 $.          # returns the entire space
JSON.GET space:1234 $.folders   # returns the folders for the space


and how that will help could you tell me more !

Edited to provide an example.
